# slope of a line question.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=(1/3)x+10$ where $f$ models the number of people joining a badminton club after $x$ years from starting.

Now the slope of $f$ is $1/3$, so that means that people are joining the club at a rate of 1/3 a year. But how can a 1/3 of a person join? Would it be better to say people are joining at a rate of 1 every 3 years?

Comment: Yes it would make more sense. I guess this shows the flaw in using a linear continuous model for a discrete event. In the same way, the average number of children per person is something like 2.2. Of course no-one has 2.2 children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the slope is just a mathematical concept. In this case it means that per unit of 1 year (since $x$ is in years) the number of people will rise with $\dfrac{1}{3}$.

Translating this to everyday life, this simply means that every 3 years, one person will join.

Note that this meaning depends entirely on the concept this function models. In this case, $f$ models a discrete quantity, which roughly means that your outcome would make more sense if it is a whole number. If for example you would measure, say, the amount of water in the oceans in liters, a rise of $\dfrac{1}{3}$ per year would make perfect sense.

Comment: If this model is only an approximation, would it be reasonable to say that after 26 years, there were either 18 or 19 members of the club. What would be the best interpretation? Thanks

Comment: If you follow the interpretation of "every 3 years one person will join", you will have to say that after 26 years there would be 18 members, simply by flooring the result of $f$. In other words, in the year 0, the club would have 10 members. In the two years following, it would continue to have 10 members, but in year 3 it will gain one, which process repeats every 3 years